# How do I get the height and width of a font in FreeGLUT?

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

If I want to write some text to screen, I might write something like this:

```
GLint const fontHeight = 13; //character height
GLint const fontWidth = 8; // character width
void * font = GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13; //font used
```

This is cumbersome, because if I change the font, I have to change those GLint values as well. To get the width, I can do this:

```
GLint const fontWidth = glutBitmapWidth(font,'x'); // character width
```

But when I try to call `glutBitmapHeight` it says the function is undefined (I'm getting these function names from here: http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php), so I'm stuck.

Comment: `gutBitmapHeight` just takes a font pointer while `glutBitmapWidth` takes a font pointer and a character. As the documentation you linked states "The fonts are designed such that all characters have (nominally) the same height.". Also make sure you're actually using FreeGLUT as this function is not present in regular GLUT

Comment: @PeterT Yes I am using freeglut, and `glutBitmapHeight`, taking only a font pointer or otherwise, is not available.